# after doing sys.path.append & PYTHONPATH me syntax error on jupyter when importing module

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook, sys

I want to upload a module mysweetlibrary.py and I am looking on stackoverflow and on documentation but it seems not working or that I miss some understanding.
My understanding is that to import a module example mysweetlibrary.py I can use sys module so `sys.path` and import it just calling it without the extension. So I am trying to do so.

After using sys.path I would like to import the module mysweetlibrary.py.
But this give me syntax error.I am using windows 10 and jupyter notebook.

I read about `sys.path` & PYTHONPATH; sets the search path for importing python modules, but didnt really get how to use it and what I am doing wrong.

```
import os
import sys
my_dir="C:\\Users\\mica7\\Documents\\Repo\\dataproc\\Sensor" 
# my_dir is the directory of the module mysweetlibrary.py and where the code ipy is located
print(my_dir)

sys.path.append( my_dir )

import mysweetlibrary as mylib
```

I have a syntax error, that I do not understand. It something is empty like something didnt work properly.

```
in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-39-c9ae4ce1a00a>", line 18, in <module>
   import mysweetlibrary as mylib

  File "C:\\Users\\mica7\\Documents\\Repo\\dataproc\\Sensor", line 184
    print sens_lista[np.where(np.asarray(fillidx)==1)[0]]
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What python version are you using? Probably python 3x?

Comment: I am using 2.7 . I have python 3, but I am running the code on a virtual environment on python 2.7 cause the code was written on 2.7

Comment: Could you share a minimal example of `mysweetlibrary `? It looks like there is a syntax error in that file.